# Prove that the integral of a rapidly oscillating function is $0$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, definite-integrals, oscillatory-integral

Claim: If $n$ is a nonzero integer, then $$\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \exp[{2in(x+\tan x)}] \ \mathrm{d}x = 0$$

Using Euler's identity $e^{ix}= \cos x + i \sin x$, the fact that $\sin$ is an odd function so integrated over a symmetric integral gives $0$, and the parity of $\cos$, one gets

$$\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \! \! \cos(2n(x+\tan x)) \ \mathrm{d}x$$

I tried using substitution, but it didn't get me anywhere. Is there maybe a general way to approach these rapidly oscillating integrals to show that the positive and negative areas cancel out?

Comment: Where did you get this integral?

Comment: When you expand your cosine, I don't think you can trivially say that the term $\sin (2nx)\sin (2n\tan x) $ is $0$, because an odd function times an odd function is even. Or is there something that I missed ?

Comment: @NHL Yes, you are right! Thank you, I edited it out

Comment: I think it's better to expand the cosine like $\cos(a+b) $

Comment: @YuriyS and after that?

Comment: Substitute $u=2 n \tan x$ and get two Bessel integrals which we will need to prove to be equal. I'll do this later when I have the time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Integrate $f(z) = \exp[2in(z+\tan z)]$ around the rectangular contour with vertices $-\pi/2,\pi/2,-\pi/2+ iR, \pi/2+iR$. ***For the moment***, ignore the singularity at $z=\pm \pi/2$.

Since $n$ is an integer, $f(z+\pi) = f(z)$, hence integrals on two vertical line cancel each other, hence
$$\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} f(z) dz = \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} f(z+iR) dz$$ for any $R>0$. But $$\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} f(z+iR) dz = e^{-2nR}\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \exp[2in(x+\tan(x+iR))]dx$$
last integral is bounded as $R\to \infty$ because $\tan$ is bounded at large imaginary argument, letting $R\to \infty$ gives $\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} f(z) dz = 0$ when $n> 0$.

Now we take account of the singularity at $z=\pm \pi/2$. Let $r$ be small positive, let $C_1$ be the circle $\pi/2 + re^{i\theta}$ with $\pi/2 \leq \theta\leq \pi$. Then I claim $\int_{C_1} f(z) dz \to 0$ as $r\to 0$. Indeed, $$\tan(\pi/2 + re^{i\theta}) = -\cot(re^{i\theta}) = -r^{-1}e^{-i\theta} + O(r)$$
so $$\int_{C_1} f(z) dz = ir\int_{\pi/2}^{\pi} \left( \exp[-2inr^{-1}e^{-i\theta}] + O(1)\right) d\theta$$
If $n>0$, ***then $\Re(-2inr^{-1}e^{-i\theta})\leq 0$ for $\theta$ in range***, the integral tends to $0$ as $r\to 0$. This take cares the singularity at $z=\pi/2$. Similar procedure handles the singularity at $z=-\pi/2$.

So we rigorously proved, when $n$ is positive integer, $$\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0^+} \int_{-\pi/2 + \varepsilon}^{\pi/2 - \varepsilon} f(x) dx = 0$$
The same is true for $n$ negative, by looking at real and imaginary part.

---

A very analogous integral $$\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \exp[2i(x-\tan x)] dx \approx 1.70067$$ is nonzero. Curious readers can identify which of step above argument fails.

Comment: Thank you! This is very illuminating. The point is the fact that integral over the whole contour is $0$ because it is closed and the integrand is an analytical function in that region, correct?

Comment: @Siupa  yes, that's a basic fact which I didn't mention.